# CollectionViewSource not updated on AppbarButtonPress

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have implemented functionality to switch between `Single` and `Multiple` selection for a `ListView`. I have created `AppBarButton` that triggers that switch. Everything is working fine except refreshing of `CollecitonViewSource`.

In the beckend the data are deleted everything works as expected but `ListView` is not displaying new data.

```
private void MultipleSelectionMode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    if (ContactsListView.SelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.Single) {
        //change selection mode to multiple
        ContactsListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple;

        //change appbar button icon
        MultipleSelectionMode.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Delete);
    }
    else if (ContactsListView.SelectionMode == ListViewSelectionMode.Multiple) {
        //remove selected items
        List<object> selectedContacts = ContactsListView.SelectedItems.ToList();

        foreach (Person person in selectedContacts) {
            //remove contact from database
            GlobalData.RemoveContact(person);
        }

        //change selection mode to single
        ContactsListView.SelectionMode = ListViewSelectionMode.Single;

        //change appbar button icon
        MultipleSelectionMode.Icon = new SymbolIcon(Symbol.Bullets);

        //new data are in groupingItems but not displayed on the screen
        groupingItems = Person.createGrouping(GlobalData.LoadContacts());
    }
}
```

This method is called when `AppBarButton` is pressed. `ContactsListView` is a `ListView` defined like this:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="ContactsListView"    
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ContactsTemplate}"
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ContactsViewSource.View}"
    Grid.Row="1">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:GroupingItem">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Key}"
                                    Foreground="Blue"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

my `CollectionViewSources` looks like this:

```
<CollectionViewSource 
    x:Name="ContactsViewSource"
    x:Key="src"
    Source="{x:Bind groupingItems, Mode=OneWay}"
    IsSourceGrouped="True" />
```

I know that the binding is working because I'm calling `groupingItems = Person.createGrouping(GlobalData.LoadContacts());` multiple times and the data are refreshed in each case. It not working only the `AppBarButton` is pressed.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: What result do you expect? Because, to me, it seems that the `selectedContacts` is empty so your data doesn't change. The reason is that you're calling this code when switching between single and multiple selection mode, but you should call it when the selected items change.

Comment: @StepTNT I've edited the question to answer your comment. The selectedContacts are not empty, the data are deleted from database and new data are loaded. But the view is not refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the TwoWay mode when use x:bind if you want to send back the change made by the user.

```
Source="{x:Bind groupingItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

x:bind default mode is one time, if you use TwoWay you are going to tell the control to update the source data of the listview every time the user change something in the UI.

and you need to use an ObservableCollection instead of a List

**Edit**

```
    public class BindableSourceConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

use this converter with the ObservableCollection

Comment: Actually this is the thing I already tried, with compilation error: Invalid binding path 'groupingItems' : Cannot bind type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection(People.Backend.GroupingItem)' to 'System.Object' without a converter.

Comment: yes, you need a converte, i'm going to update the answer with a working converter